# Blazor WASM (hosted) - CI/CD with Jenkins?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, .net-core, blazor-webassembly, continuous-deployment

Our company is currently trying out working with Blazor and we decided to go with WASM (ASP.NET-Core hosted). We are currently trying to figure out how to deploy a project via CD with Jenkins.

We want to host the project on an on-premise Ubuntu server with Jenkins but are not really sure on how to set this up correctly. We already have a private GIT repo for our project.

Until now, we published the .Server project into a folder with the following publish settings:
[image: FolderProfile - Publish settings]

After the successful publishing process we copy the contents of the folder over to our Ubuntu server. After a `sudo chmod +x ./<project>.Server`, we can execute the file and everything works like expected. We have created an `systemd` service to run the file.

When getting into Jenkins, we noticed that we have to set up a `Jenkinsfile`. How would we describe our current deployment process in this file?